# get pose from orbslam

Tags: orb, slam

Hi I need use orbslam to get the pose of camera.
I know I should use things like  `mpCurrentKeyFrame->GetPose()` to get the pose. I saw the source code the "GetPose()" function will return "Tcw". What's the meaning of Tcw here? 
If I extract "roll pitch yaw " and "x,y,z" from that Tcw, then the "roll pitch yaw" are the camera Euler angles and the "x,y,z" are the camera's position? 
I did it like that way, I use the `mpCurrentKeyFrame->GetPose()` to get the first several keyframes' pose. It returns me the following things for the first keyframe

`[0.99992567, 0.01199016, 0.0022002477, 0.00021382024;
      -0.011967794, 0.99987924, -0.0099111488, -0.026224624;
  -0.0023188184, 0.0098840808, 0.99994844, -0.0081501938;
  0, 0, 0, 1]`

If my understanding is right, [0.00021382024,-0.026224624,-0.0081501938] should be the [x,y,z]. What's the unit of these number?　Is it "meter" or others?
  Then I extract roll pitch yaw from rotation matrix, using equation [here](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node103.html)
What's the unit of the Euler angles?

Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the way to get the world position from orbslam should be

```
mpCurrentKeyframe->getInversePose()
```

The unit is still not sure yet